# Docker multi-stage builds: how to set WORKDIR globally for every stage?

Tags: dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I have many stages in my Dockerfile. Now in every stage I have copy/pasted `#WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH`:

```
FROM base as buidler
WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH

FROM buidler as test
WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH

FROM buidler as deploy
WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH
```

How can I reduce this boilerplate code and set `WORKDIR` only once globally?

What I want:

```
WORKDIR = $MY_DEFAULT_WORDIR  # Set globally for every stage


FROM base as buidler


FROM buidler as test


FROM buidler as deploy
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `FROM` line inherits almost all of the settings from its base image, including its `WORKDIR`.  Since your later stages derive from the first stage you only need to include `WORKDIR` in the base stage.

```bash
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app

FROM builder AS test
# already in /app directory

FROM builder AS deploy
# already in /app directory
```

Comment: Be warned that the `WORKDIR` is NOT honored in multistage `COPY` commands, as of today. You will need to use `COPY --from=builder /app/my-file ./`.